# Python, Tkinter, Show list as an Excel sheet ain a window just one time?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hy!

I have a list with Costumers data (Name, Address, ID) in Python and a button in Tkinter window. When I click on "Show List_1" button then I see the list as a table use treeview so it works. When I click again, then I see two times the table, when click again then tree times. How does it work show the list just one time and just "refresh" the window, when I click on the button to show it?

I tried to use treeview.delete and destroy() function, but then when I click on the button I see nothing, happens nothing.

```py
def Vevok_Listazasa():
    
    Lista = [Vevok("ID_1","Ceg_1","Cim_1"),
             Vevok("ID_2","Ceg_2","Cim_2"),
             Vevok("ID_3","Ceg_3","Cim_3")]
    
    tree = ttk.Treeview(window, column=("c1","c2","c3"), show='headings')   
    tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER)
    tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
    tree.column("#2", anchor=CENTER)
    tree.heading("#2", text="Vevo_Nev")
    tree.column("#3", anchor=CENTER)
    tree.heading("#3", text="Ceg_cim")
    
    index = iid = 0

    for item in Lista:
        tree.insert("", index, iid, values=item)
        index = iid = index+1
    
    tree.pack()
    tree.destroy()
```

Comment: You should include code that shows the problem you are experiencing, specifically a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can create the treeview once outside the function and just refresh its content inside the function:

```py
def Vevok_Listazasa():
    # clear the treeview
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

    # populate new data
    Lista = [Vevok("ID_1","Ceg_1","Cim_1"),
             Vevok("ID_2","Ceg_2","Cim_2"),
             Vevok("ID_3","Ceg_3","Cim_3")]

    index = iid = 0

    for item in Lista:
        tree.insert("", index, iid, values=item)
        index = iid = index+1

tree = ttk.Treeview(window, column=("c1","c2","c3"), show='headings')
tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
tree.column("#2", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#2", text="Vevo_Nev")
tree.column("#3", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#3", text="Ceg_cim")
tree.pack()
```